# Change app icon by code - android studio run does not work anymore

Tags: android, android-manifest, alias

I use a function like this to change my apps icon if the user wishes to do so:

```
 public static void changeIcon(Activity activity, String addon)
{
    // 1) adactivate all aliases
    List<String> names = AppIconStyle.getNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < AppIconStyle.getNames().size(); i++)
    {
        ComponentName componentNameToDeactivate = new ComponentName(activity.getPackageName(), MainActivityMVP.class.getName() + "-" + names.get(i));
        activity.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentNameToDeactivate, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
    // 2) activate selected alias
    ComponentName componentNameToActivate = new ComponentName(activity.getPackageName(), MainActivityMVP.class.getName() + "-" + addon);
    activity.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentNameToActivate, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

The problem is, android studio run does always try to start the default alias which I changed on my device... So it does not find the default activity, because this one is deactivated...

**Question**

I know I can define an activity in android studio run config, but actually I would like to have one config that starts whichever alias currently is active on my device. Is that somehow possible? Something like *"check the manifest and try to start one launcher activity after another until one works"* or so...

Answer (score -1):

Add permissions in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

```
Intent myLauncherIntent = new Intent();
```

myLauncherIntent.setClassName("your.package.name", "YourLauncherActivityName");
myLauncherIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, myLauncherIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Application Name");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.app_icon));
intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: this does not solve the problem, and just show another way to change icon, the problem is android studio cannot detect the selected activity-alias, how to solve this?

Comment: which android version you are using?